# what's wrong in where condition statement

Tags: asp.net

```
SqlConnection con = 
   new SqlConnection
     (@"Data Source=SAMA-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=advCenter;
          Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand(
     "select visited_link 
      from links 
      where [user_email]=@ue and [visited_link]=@vl",con);
com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ue",Convert.ToString(Session["mail"]));
com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vl", ImageButton1.ID);
con.Open();
SqlDataReader dr;
dr = com1.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.HasRows)
{
    Label2.Text = "wrong";
}
```

Comment: What kind of error (if any) do you get?

Comment: The error message would be helpful.

Comment: the error message is :The data types ntext and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator. but if i made one condition without and visited_link=@vl the statment goes true

Comment: you have tons of questions like this with no explanation and let so much people working for you but don't accepting any answers. what is your intention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
"... and  CAST([visited_link] AS NVARCHAR(MAX))=@vl "
```

---

Refer to the following

[CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

[HOW TO: Compare Values in NTEXT Field](http://www.willstrohl.com/Blog/EntryId/124/HOW-TO-Compare-Values-in-NTEXT-Field)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try

```
command.Parameters.Add("@ue", SqlDbType.NText)
command.Parameters("@ue").Value = Convert.ToString(Session["mail"]);
```

to explicitly specify the column data type.

Comment: Like Bala R said, you need to specify the type. However, based on what you added. I am not sure that the use of a ntext column type is appropriate anyway. I think if you changed your DB schema from ntext to nvarchar(max) (which is probably still more than necessary for a link) you would not need to specify the type and it would work. Specifying the type won't hurt and is probably a good practice.